# C++ Threads writing to different parts of array of vector

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I have an `std::array<std::vector, NUM_THREADS>` and I basically want each thread to go get some data, and store it in its own `std::vector`, and also to read from its vector.

Is this safe?  Or am I going to have to use a mutex or something?

Comment: If each thread have it's own separate vector, then it should be safe, Remember that the "array" of `std::array` is fixed at compilation time.

Comment: Okay!  Yep, I know the number of threads at compile time to the `array` is fine.  Each thread will only write to its own thread, but the other threads may need to read from any of the `vector`s, do you know if any thread reading from any vector at any time is safe?  I can see that writing to the same vector at the same time could cause issues.

Comment: Ah, if *other* threads are reading from other threads vectors, then it's not thread safe, and you need locking.

Answer (score 2):

The rule regarding data-races is that if every memory location is either accessed by no more than one thread at a time, or is only read (by any number of threads, but no writes), you don't need atomicity.  Otherwise, you need either atomicity or synchronization (such as mutual-exclusion).

If every thread is only writing to and reading from its own vector, this would be safe.  If two threads are writing to the same vector elements without synchronization, or if they're both writing to the same vector *itself* (e.g., appending or truncating the vector), you're pretty much clobbered --- that's two simultaneous writes.  If two threads are each writing to elements of their own vectors and reading from both vectors, it's more complicated, but in general I would expect it to be unsafe.  There are very specific arrangements where it may be safe/legal, but they will be very brittle, and likely hard to maintain, so it's probably better to re-architect to avoid it.

As an example of a usage like this where it would be legal (but again, brittle and hard to retain safety during code maintenance) would be where none of the vectors are changing size (a reallocation is going to be a write to the vector *itself* which would preclude any reads on the vector or its elements by other threads) and each thread is able to avoid reading from any *specific* element of a vector that is written to by any other thread (for example, you have two threads, one reading from and writing to even elements of the vectors and the other reading from and writing to odd elements of the vectors).

The above example is very artificial and probably not all that useful for real access patterns that might be desired.  Other examples I could think of would probably also be artificial and unhelpful.  And it's very easy to do some simple operation that would destroy the whole guarantee.  In particular, if any thread performs `push_back()` on their own vector, any threads that may be concurrently reading the vector are almost guaranteed to result in undefined behavior.  (You might be able to align the stars using `reserve()` very carefully and make code that is legal, but I certainly wouldn't attempt it myself.)